# $\int_{-2}^2 \sin\left(x^5\right)\, e^{(x^8)\sin(x^4)}\,dx\;$: integration by parts or substitution?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\large\int_{-2}^2 \sin\left(x^5\right)\, e^{(x^8)\sin(x^4)}\,dx$$

I think I should solve it by parts but I'm really confused. It seems as a hard question.

Comment: i think there is no Chance to find this integral or you will go on a numerical way

Comment: same exercise sheet?
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2142105/int-22-sinx5ex8-sinx4-dx

Answer (score 1):

The integrand is odd, so the answer is $0$.

Comment: All too easy.  (+1)